# Using unsigned long long int for dynamic allocation

Tags: c

If I have the following variable `unsigned long long int *size`, is it a good practice to leave `size = calloc(2, sizeof(int))` or it should be `size = calloc(2, sizeof(unsigned long long int))` ?

Thank you

Comment: Well, are `int` and `unsigned long long int` the same size on your platform?

Comment: Better practice to use `size = calloc(2, sizeof *size);` for fewer errors and more maintainable code.

Comment: @DavidBowling Good idea. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Second option. You don't want to make assumptions about datatype sizes in c.
It is very platform/compiler dependent.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to assume that `int`and `unsigned long long int` are the same size (they may be). If `size` is declared as `unsigned long long int`, then of the two options presented, the correct choice is:

```
size = calloc(2, sizeof(unsigned long long int));
```

A better practice is to avoid using explicit types with `sizeof`:

```
size = calloc(2, sizeof *size);
```

This is less error-prone in the initial coding, and more maintainable. If types change during the lifetime of the code, only the declaration needs to be changed here.

Comment: Is this also a valid argument for other datatypes? For instance `double *length = calloc(2, sizeof *length);`

Comment: @Medoo-- yes. This is a common C idiom. Note that the argument is not evaluated (in most cases), so even if `size` is uninitialized, this is OK. That is, `sizeof *size;` does not dereference the pointer `size`; it only determines the size of the argument from the type.

Comment: Just leaned this. Thank you very much. Will be using it from now on :)

Comment: @Medoo-- example: `int (*)row[5] =  malloc(sizeof *row * num_rows);` Here, `row`  is a pointer to an array of 5 `int`s, and enough space is allocated for `num_rows` of rows, or a `num_rows` X 5 array.

Comment: @Medoo-- consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer if this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The size of int can be either 2 or 4 bytes, depending on the machine you run.
However, the size of unsigned long long is at least 8 bytes.

So no, it is **NOT** a good practice to use a worng size.

Comment: An `int` must be _at least_ 16 bits wide, but there is no upper limit set in the Standard.